# Can't assign tags in Rails 4.2 from model form using acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to use the acts_as_taggable_on gem.  Everything works in console, I can asoicate tags with a model instance, render the tag_list and link to a results page based on the tag chosen.  My issue is that my tags entered into the create form do not save in the db.  I have already checked strong_params:

`params.require(:contest).permit(:name, :description, :user_id, :show_name, :tag_list => [],...`

Comment: Some code reference would be usefull here.

Comment: Try debugging what comes through that permit. I tink you'd be surprised.

Comment: newbie here.  how do I debug the permit?

Comment: You can  outputting the result of that permit in a debug log using `Rails.logger.debug` to see what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Rails 4.2, ruby 2.2, and acts-as-taggable-on 3.4 app. I changed the params in the controller to update the model. Originally, I had

```
  def update
@post = Post.find(params[:id])

if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :tag_list => []))
  redirect_to @post
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

end

I changed the params :tag_list => [] to just :tag_list. It works. My code now looks like the following:

```
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :tag_list))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  def tagged
    if params[:tag].present?
      @post = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.postall
    end
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, :image2, :tag_list => [])
    end
```

Hope this helps.